# python : identify first line that starts with search1 after search2 without iterating through entire file

Tags: python

Problem :
Identify first timestamp after every Server 1

Problem 2:
Expected output :

```
Time 02:02:02
Time 03:03:03
```

Tried :  `re.findall(r'Server 1, Problem 2.*Time: \d+:\d+:\d+', text, re.DOTALL)` but that prints `04:04:04`. Cant get it to work with `re.MULTILINE` as the number of lines between search & time can vary. Tried split option using delimiter of Time, but as split returns list of words not able to search through it with re.search or `re.findall` (cant get index to work either) . Any suggestions without having to iterate through entire file?

```
Server 1, Problem 1
Time : 01:01:01
Server 1, Problem 2
Server 2, Problem 2
Time: 02:02:02
Server 1, Problem 2
Server 2, Problem 2
Server 3, Problem 3
Time: 03:03:03
Server 4, Problem 4
Time : 04:04:04
```

Comment: Server 1, Problem 1

Comment: You have to iterate through the entire file. You can't know if a specific line doesn't exists unless you check all the lines.

Comment: thanks, wanted to confirm there was no other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate the entire file to find the information you're looking for. Regex does this anyway, so you're not skipping the iterating by using it. Here's how you could solve this problem:

```
times = []
capture_next_time = False
with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip() 
        if line == 'Server 1, Problem 2':
            capture_next_time = True
        elif line.startswith("Time:") and capture_next_time:
            times.append(line)
            capture_next_time = False
print(times)
# >> ['Time: 02:02:02', 'Time: 03:03:03']
```

If you're worried because the file is huge, this method uses an `iterator` instead of loading the entire file to memory, so that only a single line is handled in each cycle of the loop.

Edit:

Here's the [multiline regex](https://regex101.com/r/pDM0E2/1) if you'd rather have a single line solution (although performance would be worse):

```
r"Server 1, Problem 2[^\:]*(Time: \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2})"gm
```

In essence, this regex finds your problem string, matches until it finds a character that is unique to the time line (T would also work), and then captures that line.

Comment: thanks. I had a similar logic if I had to iterate through the entire file

Comment: All good - remember to accept the answer if I've answered your question. That stops others from attempting an already "answered" question. If I haven't given you what you needed let me know, and we can work towards a better solution!

Comment: I've also updated my question with the regex version of the answer, but I would advise against it for the sake of readability and performance. However, it is more concise.

Comment: was curious how I would do it with regex, thank you again